# Allow items in flexbox to evenly align themselves to container's edges without space-between

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

Sorry if this question is obvious and I am missing something. I am creating a site which has a flexbox container with elements inside it that wrap around. I want my items inside the container to stretch to the edge of the container to ensure there is the correct amount of whitespace. I can achieve this by using justify-content: space-between but when there is a row with more than one item and less than four they still must space themselves. How can I fix this problem? I don't want to use flex-start and adjust the margin between the items because that seems inaccurate and a problem for responsiveness. Below is my code for the flex container.

```
.clothingitems {
display: flex;
flex-flow: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: white;
}

.clothingitem {
width: 265px;
height: 450px;
display: flex;
flex-flow: column;
}
```

There is a live website but beware the page I'm mentioning has not been made responsive. It can be found here: [Site here](https://observer-archive.firebaseapp.com/feed.html)

Thank you.

Comment: you could add the html as well and make a working example here?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a CSS grid for this, and using media breakpoints to make it responsive, instead of a horizontal flex with wrap. Here is an example of a grid with each column taking up 15% in width and 5% `column-gap` between them.

```
<div class="clothingitems">
  <div class="clothingitem"></div>
  <div class="clothingitem"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

```
.clothingitems {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 15% 15% 15% 15% 15%;
    column-gap: 5%;
    row-gap: 50px;
}
```